# Formatting Errors with tail

Tags: linux, bash, unicode, cygwin, tail

**How can I correctly parse this file through `tail`, without formatting errors?**

I am using `tail` within `cygwin` to parse the last ten lines of two files. One file parses through correctly, the other contains a space between every character.

```
$ tail file2.txt -n 4
22/06/2015 12:28 - Decompressing and saving profile extract...
22/06/2015 12:28 - Decompressing and saving profile extract...
22/06/2015 12:38 - Decompressing and saving profile extract...
22/06/2015 12:38 - Decompressing and saving profile extract...

$ tail file1.txt -n 4
P a c k a g e   s t a r t .
E l a p s e d   t i m e :   5 0 . 1 7 5 7 5 4 8   s e c s .
. . . P a c k a g e   E x e c u t e d .

R e s u l t :   S u c c e s s
```

When I read the raw contents of the file in python I get the folllowing, whjich I think is a load of unicode characters

```
In [1]: open('file1.text', 'r').read()
Out[1]: '\xff\xfeP\x00a\x00c\x00k\x00a\x00g\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00t\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00.\x00\r\x00\n\x00E\x00l\x00a\x00p\x00s\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00t\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00:\x00 \x005\x000\x00.\x001\x007\x005\x007\x005\x004\x008\x00 \x00s\x00e\x00c\x00s\x00.\x00\r\x00\n\x00.\x00.\x00.\x00P\x00a\x00c\x00k\x00a\x00g\x00e\x00 \x00E\x00x\x00e\x00c\x00u\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00.\x00\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00\n\x00R\x00e\x00s\x00u\x00l\x00t\x00:\x00 \x00S\x00u\x00c\x00c\x00e\x00s\x00s\x00\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00\n\x00'
In [2]: print open('temp.txt', 'r').read()
■P a c k a g e   s t a r t .
E l a p s e d   t i m e :   5 0 . 1 7 5 7 5 4 8   s e c s .
. . . P a c k a g e   E x e c u t e d .

R e s u l t :   S u c c e s s
```

When I copy the entire content of `file1.txt` into a new file `test.txt` - the issue does not reoccur.

```
$ tail test.txt
Package start.
Elapsed time: 50.1757548 secs.
...Package Executed.

Result: Success
```

The file seems to have the characters `\x00` between every character and `\xff` at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is in UTF-16 format, which uses 2 8-bit bytes to represent most characters (and 4 8-bit bytes for some characters). Each of the 128 ASCII characters is represented as 2 bytes, a zero byte and a byte containing the actual character value. The `\xff\xfe` sequence at the start is a Byte Order Mark (BOM); it indicates whether the remaining characters are represented with the high-order or low-order byte first.

UTF-16 is one of several ways to represent Unicode text. It's most commonly used in Microsoft Windows.

I'm not sure why the null characters appear as spaces. That may be due to the way your terminal emulator behaves.

Use the `iconv` command to convert the file from UTF-16 to some other format.

Comment: you are correct, `file file1.txt` gave: `Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: is it possible to do `iconv` on-the-fly when using `tail -f`?

Comment: `$ luit -encoding UTF-8 tail -f file1.txt` solved it for me.